# Coordinate descent for the lasso or elastic net

Tags: regression, references, lasso, regularization, elastic-net

Are there any good papers or books dealing with the use of coordinate descent for L1 (lasso) and/or elastic net regularization for linear regression problems?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I earlier suggested the recent paper by Friedman and coll., [Regularization Paths for Generalized Linear Models via Coordinate Descent](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i01/paper), published in the Journal of Statistical Software (2010). Here are some other references that might be useful:

- [Pathwise coordinate optimization](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/stat315a/Supplements/fuse.pdf), by Friedman and coll.
- [Fast Regularization Paths via Coordinate Descent](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~hastie/TALKS/glmnet.pdf), by Hastie (UseR! 2009)
- [Coordinate descent algorithms for lasso penalized regression](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1206367819), by Wu and Lange (Ann. Appl. Stat. 2(1): 224-244, 2008; also on available on [arXiv.org](http://arxiv.org/))
- [Coordinate Descent for Sparse Solutions of Underdetermined Linear Systems of Equations](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~aey/sparse/sparse9.pdf), by Yagle (a bit too complex for me)

Comment: Thanks for the references. Incidentally, the paper by Friedman et al partially answers a related question I've just posted, about the relative performance of coordinate descent vs LARS.

Comment: "A brief history of coordinate descent for the lasso" on pp15-17 of the UseR! talk is a gem :-)

Answer (score 5):

I've just come across this [lecture](https://web.archive.org/web/20100904040041/http://videolectures.net/kdd08_hastie_rpcd/) by Hastie and thought that others might find it interesting.

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to open the video. I am very interested to Watch it

Comment: @Christina It seems to be working at the moment. However you need to have Flash enabled. I cannot find a download link, so there seems no choice but to enable Flash and watch it streaming.